# asp.net website listbox selectedindex

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

    }
```

if `label2.text` is written in page load then its output is -1

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
```

if i write `label2.text` in selected index change it returns nothing.
please help me out.

Comment: The first case is normal as a value of -1 is returned if no item is selected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is autopostback set to true on the listbox?